# Query to find gaps in zip4 codes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a `T-SQL` query to find all zip codes that have gaps in their `zip4` ranges. Here are sample tables of my data:

Zip ranges:

```
Zip    minRangeZip4    maxRangeZip4

85005    0                  6505
85005    6506                9999
85006     0                  5555
85006     5559               9999
```

How would I write a query to pick up that there's a gap between the `zip4` range for `85006`?

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of rows with the same Zip value?

Comment: No I have zipcodes with 40 different zip ranges. I have a different tax rate for each zip range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on sql server 2012, you could use `Lead` (or `Lag`) as below.

```
;with cte as (
  select Zip, minRangeZip4, maxRangeZip4,
        lead(minRangeZip4) over (partition by zip order by minRangeZip4) leadVal
from t
) 
select Zip 
from cte 
where maxRangeZip4 +1 <> leadVal    
order by Zip
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c013/17)

Results

```
|   ZIP |
---------
| 85006 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the difference between the max and min range for each row and then sum those differences for each zip, you will be able to identify which zip codes don't have the full range.  The sum of the differences will be 10,000 for zips where there are no gaps, and it will be less than 10,000 for zips where there are gaps.

```
SELECT zip, SUM(maxRangeZip4-minRangeZip4+1) 
FROM zips
GROUP BY zip
HAVING SUM(maxRangeZip4-minRangeZip4+1) <> 10000
```

Here is the example with data setup in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9ee1/1/0). I tested this on SQL Server 2008, and it should work on other database versions also.

Note: When taking the difference between maxRangeZip4 and minRangeZip4, we need to add 1 because the count of codes needs to be inclusive of the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple math this query will give you zips that have a gap assuming that the zip will not always start with 0

```
SELECT zip, SUM(maxzip)-SUM(minzip)+MIN(minzip)+COUNT(*)-1-MAX(maxzip) AS missing
FROM ranges
GROUP BY zip
HAVING missing <> 0
```

If the zip always start with 0, just remove the `min(minzip)`

both queries are shown in the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f94545/4)